# Android app shutting down, but issue not found on android activity

Tags: android

I need your help finding the issue on an android activity.

I am not able to find the reason inside the log text. This is my activity code:

```
package com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button ofertasbutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        addListenerOfertasButton();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    public void addListenerOfertasButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        ofertasbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOfertas);

        ofertasbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, categorias_list.class);
                            startActivity(intent);   

            }

        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

The app is executed and just after showing the app title, it crashes with the message: Unfortunately Vive Gran Canaria has stopped. And this is the log text

```
04-05 19:59:28.604: D/AndroidRuntime(1206): Shutting down VM
    04-05 19:59:28.604: W/dalvikvm(1206): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a39ba8)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Process: com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria, PID: 1206
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.MainActivity.addListenerOfertasButton(MainActivity.java:44)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     ... 11 more
    04-05 19:59:28.624: W/ActivityManager(378):   Force finishing activity com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/.MainActivity
    04-05 19:59:28.954: I/WindowManager(378): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b4fabe30 ActivityRecord{b4cda2e8 u0 com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/.MainActivity t6 f}} appWin=Window{b4f87c80 u0 Starting com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria} drawState=4
    04-05 19:59:28.954: W/WindowManager(378): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (240x400) to layer 21010
    04-05 19:59:29.114: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:29.374: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:29.454: W/ActivityManager(378): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b4cda2e8 u0 com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/.MainActivity t6 f}
    04-05 19:59:29.494: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:29.684: I/Choreographer(534): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:29.884: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.004: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.064: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.154: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.214: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.264: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.314: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.354: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.424: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.454: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:30.524: I/Choreographer(378): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    04-05 19:59:37.724: E/WindowManager(378): Starting window AppWindowToken{b5087a70 token=Token{b4fabe30 ActivityRecord{b4cda2e8 u0 com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/.MainActivity t6}}} timed out
    04-05 19:59:40.014: W/ActivityManager(378): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b4cda2e8 u0 com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/.MainActivity t6 f}
```

Comment: Does a Button with id `btnOfertas` exist in your activity_main.xml? Or is it in your Fragment (`fragment_main.xml`)?

Comment: @JustinJasmann, it is in fragment_main.xml.

Comment: That would be the issue. Added answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your button is in `fragment_main.xml` (not `activity_main.xml`) then you'll need to move your `setOnClickListener` logic into your fragment class.

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    Button ofertasbutton;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        ofertasbutton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOfertas);
        ofertasbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, categorias_list.class);
                startActivity(intent);   
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,this is the first time I am working with fragments, and I don't understand it very good. I don't have any fragment class.

Comment: I agree with you @mvasco, having fragments causing issues in understanding newly. Earlier it used to be very simple by just simply extending to activity and simple default code now it is messy looking at the default code. And BTW, I'm going to use justin's answer as a reference in future to how to make use of fragment's default code and put my code in to it. Thanks Justin !

Comment: No problem! I actually had a very difficult time trying to figure out fragments myself. All of the default Android templates changed to include this fragment piece and I was getting the same `NullPointerException`.

Comment: The fragment design is quite similar to how you used to design activities, where the fragment looks after it's own UI controls and has member variables for each, etc. It's different, but nice. Happy coding :D!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the LogCat, you have a null pointer exception, which causes the crash. I can't tell you which line is the reason for it. But look closer at line 44.

```
04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.MainActivity.addListenerOfertasButton(MainActivity.java:44)
04-05 19:59:28.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1206):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
```

-- EDIT
If your button is only present in the fragment layout, then you need should add first the fragment and after that, set the onCLickListener.

Answer (score 1):

You must call your addListenerOfertasButton() method inside onCreateView(), on your PlaceHolderFragment, because the buton is part of your fragment layout. Remove it from onCreate() and put it in onCreateView(). Like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
addListenerOfertasButton();
return rootView;
}
```

And Declare your ofertasbutton `Button` like this:

```
ofertasbutton= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOfertas);
```